# SQL Query not working -- operator missing

Tags: c#, sql

I've looked though more SQL problems than I care to count but nothing seems to be working for this particular issue. I'm running a SELECT query against an access database in C# using the following code:

```
DateTime starttime = new DateTime(2011, 9, 4);
DateTime endtime = new DateTime(2011, 9, 10);

cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT ACT_ENTRY2CASE,ACT_ENTRY2USER FROM SA_TABLE_ACT_ENTRY WHERE ENTRY_TIME>" + starttime + @" AND ENTRY_TIME<" + endtime + @" AND ACT_ENTRY2CASE IS NOT NULL";
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I get the error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
>   'ENTRY_TIME>9/4/2011 12:00:00 AM AND ENTRY_TIME<9/10/2011 12:00:00 AM
>   AND ACT_ENTRY2CASE IS NOT NULL'.

I have tried surrounding my variables with various things (parentheses, ' marks, [], etc). Nothing seems to make it work (although with some of those items the error changes to something to the effect of "missing or invalid parameter".

I'm sure it's a matter of some dumb little typo on my part but I can't find it for the life of me. Any ideas?

Comment: Use parameterised queries with parameters of correct datatype. Your string literals are not quoted which is the cause of the error. Even if you fix that the datetime format is ambiguous and even if you fix that you still probably will be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Your should parametrize your query. Here is "teh codez":

```
cmd.CommandText = @"
   SELECT ACT_ENTRY2CASE,ACT_ENTRY2USER 
   FROM SA_TABLE_ACT_ENTRY 
   WHERE ENTRY_TIME> @starttime 
   AND ENTRY_TIME< @endtime 
   AND ACT_ENTRY2CASE IS NOT NULL";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starttime", starttime);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endtime ", endtime );

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Minor quibble: the code is only vulnerable to SQL injection if the values being concatenated come from unfiltered user input. Even so, parameterizing the query is the right thing to do.

Comment: That did the trick thanks! I am aware that my code was vulnerable to SQL injection but I wasn't too worried about it since it's only going to be used by me to automate some reports. Nothing public facing.

Comment: You know, it is always like that about SQL Injection. "I'm not worried right now", "It's just something in the Intranet", "It's just Sandbox". You know where I want to get to...

Answer (score 4):

You need to either put your starttime and endtime within quotations (if you just have a string representation of date in your database) or use To_Date() sql function to convert your dates to a sql date object...

However it's always best to parameterize your sql to make it safe and to raise performance.

Comment: +1 - **parametrized queries** should be the only way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is all of the problem, but I think you need to have your dates in quotes. You may have tried this and missed one, which would give you mismatched quotes.